# Solution to Kickstart's Wiggle Walk

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I'm trying to optimize my solution to [Wiggle Walk](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050ff2/0000000000150aac) for Kickstart's round 1C.

> **Problem**
>
> Banny has just bought a new programmable robot. Eager to test his
>   coding skills, he has placed the robot in a grid of squares with R
>   rows (numbered 1 to R from north to south) and C columns (numbered 1
>   to C from west to east). The square in row r and column c is denoted
>   (r, c).
>
> Initially the robot starts in the square (SR, SC). Banny will give the
>   robot N instructions. Each instruction is one of N, S, E or W,
>   instructing the robot to move one square north, south, east or west
>   respectively.
>
> If the robot moves into a square that it has been in before, the robot
>   will continue moving in the same direction until it reaches a square
>   that it has not been in before. Banny will never give the robot an
>   instruction that will cause it to move out of the grid.
>
> Can you help Banny determine which square the robot will finish in,
>   after following the N instructions?
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test
>   cases follow. Each test case starts with a line containing the five
>   integers N, R, C, SR and SC, the number of instructions, the number of
>   rows, the number of columns, the robot's starting row and starting
>   column, respectively.
>
> Then, another line follows containing a single string of N characters;
>   the i-th of these characters is the i-th instruction Banny gives the
>   robot (one of N, S, E or W, as described above).
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: r c, where x
>   is the test case number (starting from 1), r is the row the robot
>   finishes in and c is the column the robot finishes in.
>
> **Limits**
>
> Memory limit: 1GB. 1 ≤ T ≤ 100. 1 ≤ R ≤ 5 × 104. 1 ≤ C ≤ 5 × 104. 1 ≤
>   SR ≤ R. 1 ≤ SC ≤ C. The instructions will not cause the robot to move
>   out of the grid. Test set 1 (Visible)
>
> Time limit: 20 seconds. 1 ≤ N ≤ 100. Test set 2 (Hidden)
>
> Time limit: 60 seconds. 1 ≤ N ≤ 5 × 104.

Here's my current solution:

```
def main():
    T = int(input())  # the number of test cases

    for case in range(1, T+1):
        N, R, C, r, c = map(int, input().split())
        instructions = input()  # string of N, S, E or W
        seen = {(r, c)}

        for i in instructions:
            if i == 'N':
                r -= 1
                while (r, c) in seen:
                    r -= 1
            elif i == 'S':
                r += 1
                while (r, c) in seen:
                    r += 1
            elif i == 'E':
                c += 1
                while (r, c) in seen:
                    c += 1
            else:  # 'W'
                c -= 1
                while (r, c) in seen:
                    c -= 1
            seen.add((r, c))

        print('Case #{}: {} {}'.format(case, r, c))


main()
```

How can I represent visited areas in the grid so that getting the destination cell for each instruction would be faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple dictionary will do once you get the idea ;)

```
def get_neighbor(r, c, i, neighbors):
    if (r, c, i) in neighbors:
        return neighbors[(r, c, i)]

    if i == 'N':
        return (r - 1, c)
    elif i == 'S':
        return (r + 1, c)
    elif i == 'E':
        return (r, c + 1)
    else:  # 'W'
        return (r, c - 1)


def link_neighbors(r, c, neighbors):
    north = get_neighbor(r, c, 'N', neighbors)
    south = get_neighbor(r, c, 'S', neighbors)
    east = get_neighbor(r, c, 'E', neighbors)
    west = get_neighbor(r, c, 'W', neighbors)

    neighbors[(*north, 'S')] = south
    neighbors[(*south, 'N')] = north
    neighbors[(*east, 'W')] = west
    neighbors[(*west, 'E')] = east


def main():
    T = int(input())  # the number of test cases

    for case in range(1, T+1):
        N, R, C, r, c = map(int, input().split())
        instructions = input()  # string of N, S, E or W
        neighbors = {}

        for i in instructions:
            link_neighbors(r, c, neighbors)
            r, c = get_neighbor(r, c, i, neighbors)  # new position

        print('Case #{}: {} {}'.format(case, r, c))


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have participated in Google kickstart wiggle walk.

I have optimized the solution to be \$\mathcal{O}(N\times logN)\$ but it's still getting "time limit exceeded".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int t, n ,*arr, r , c, sr,sc,i=0;
    arr=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    char temp;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int z=1;
    while(z<=t)
    {
        int k=0;
        do {
            scanf("%d%c",arr+k,&temp);
            k++;
        } while(temp!='\n');
        n=*(arr);
        r=*(arr+1);
        c=*(arr+2);
        sr=*(arr+3);
        sc=*(arr+4);
        char *string;
        string =(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
        int *grid = (int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));
        int *northgrid =(int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));
        int *southgrid = (int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));
        int *eastgrid =(int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));
        int *westgrid = (int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));
        int current_sr,current_sc;
        *(grid + sr*c + sc)=1;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%c",string+j);
            current_sr = sr;
            current_sc = sc;

            if(*(string+j)=='N')
            {
                do
                {
                    if(*(northgrid + sr*c + sc)==0)
                    {

                        sr--;

                    }
                    else if(*(northgrid + sr*c + sc)!=0)
                    {
                        while(*(northgrid + sr*c + sc)!=0)
                        {
                            sr=*(northgrid + sr*c + sc);
                        }
                    }
                } while(*(grid + sr*c + sc)==1);
                *(grid + sr*c + sc)=1;
                *(southgrid+ sr*c + sc)=current_sr;
                *(northgrid+current_sr*c+current_sc)=sr;
            }
            else if(*(string+j)=='S')
            {
                do
                {
                    if(*(southgrid + sr*c + sc)==0)
                    {

                        sr++;

                    }
                    else if(*(southgrid + sr*c + sc)!=0)
                    {
                        while(*(southgrid + sr*c + sc)!=0)
                        {
                            sr=*(southgrid + sr*c + sc);
                        }
                    }
                } while(*(grid + sr*c + sc)==1);
                *(grid + sr*c + sc)=1;
                *(northgrid+ sr*c + sc)=current_sr;
                *(southgrid+current_sr*c+current_sc)=sr;
            }
            else if(*(string+j)=='E')
            {
                do
                {
                    if(*(eastgrid + sr*c + sc)==0)
                    {

                        sc++;

                    }
                    else if(*(eastgrid + sr*c + sc)!=0)
                    {
                        while(*(eastgrid + sr*c + sc)!=0)
                        {
                            sr=*(eastgrid + sr*c + sc);
                        }
                    }
                } while(*(grid + sr*c + sc)==1);
                *(grid + sr*c + sc)=1;
                *(westgrid+ sr*c + sc)=current_sc;
                *(eastgrid+current_sr*c+current_sc)=sc;
            }
            else if(*(string+j)=='W')
            {
                do
                {
                    if(*(westgrid + sr*c + sc)==0)
                    {

                        sc--;

                    }
                    else if(*(westgrid + sr*c + sc)!=0)
                    {
                        while(*(westgrid + sr*c + sc)!=0)
                        {
                            sc=*(westgrid + sr*c + sc);
                        }
                    }
                } while(*(grid + sr*c + sc)==1);
                *(grid + sr*c + sc)=1;
                *(eastgrid+ sr*c + sc)=current_sc;
                *(westgrid+current_sr*c+current_sc)=sc;
            }
            // printf("Values are: %d , %d",sr,sc);
        }
        printf("Case #%d: %d %d\n",z,sr,sc);

        z++  ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do something about the formatting. Your entire question is one big code block. That being said, is this an answer to the question? Check out the help center: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution to the problem in another language, but have not reviewed the code (see [Why are alternative solutions not welcome?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8403/92478)). And also have a look at [answer], which was already pointed out to you in the previous comment. To me it sounds more like you should ask this as a new question here on Code Review.